# C# backspace simulator deletes entire word instead of just a letter

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

I am writing a simple C# program in which when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> I want my program to automatically delete the character directly left of the cursor in any program (ex: chrome browser, word document, powerpoint document, etc...).

I have installed a global hook for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and it works fine.
I am using a keyboard simulator that I found on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library).

My issue is that when I simulate a backspace like:

```
KeyboardSimulator.KeyPress(Keys.Back);
```

the entire word is deleted instead of just the character to the left of the cursor.

For example, if I am in a Microsoft Word document with the following line of text:

> "Happy new year"

and my cursor is at the end of "year", then when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, my program deletes "year" and puts the cursor just to the right of "new" — instead of just deleting the letter "r" in "year".

I have tried other simulators as well with the same result.

Does anyone have a solution or know what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: you'll probably need to show your code before anyone can help

Comment: Why bother with a "KeyboardSimulator" when `SendKeys` does what you need? Install the hook.. and use sendkeys when the hook is hit. `SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> commonly means delete the entire word in Windows.

So when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, and your hook simulates the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, the program instead sees <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> because the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is down.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the shortcut to shift+g and it worked. Also, a work around to keep ctrl+g as a shortcut is to add:
KeyboardSimulator.KeyUp(Keys.Control);